# How to test delete query Firebase/mockFirebase in React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs

I am building an App using React Native and Firebase, and I want to test Delete function using jest/firestore-jest-mock.

My Problem is when I try this query it always return True.

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "firestore-jest-mock": "^0.7.1",
    "jest-expo": "^40.0.1",
 },
```

Here is my code:

```
// Fake DATABASE
mockFirebase({
    database: {
       categories_costs: [{ id: 'key1',title: 'test1', icon: 'icontest1' }],
   },
});

const firebase = require('firebase');
const db = firebase.firestore();

// test with wrong ID
test('Delete Document In categories_income', () => {
return db.collection('categories_costs')
    .doc('keyNoExist')
    .delete()
    .then(() => {

          //Always get into this part  
          console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
    });
 });
```

The test passed correctly like this although the id is wrong.

Comment: Is deleting a missing document *supposed* to error out? The postcondition for deletion, that the document doesn't exist, is met.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought in my code that I will always get to the catch Error because the document doesn't exist ? Or I am understanding something wrong ?

Comment: I just fixed should i update  it again or answer my question ?

Comment: It seems like all the library does when you delete is call a mock function, it doesn't check whether the document existed, or remove anything from the data. Note that you shouldn't really be mocking Firestore at all, you don't own that interface.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i just post a solution that check the document first and then remove it and in this case works fine as expected (At least as I expected)! Please let me know if you see any Improvement !

Comment: @jonrsharpe In the solution it throws an Error if I change the ID (wrong key) of the document and this exactly what I want to test

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for it, in this part it check if the document exist and then remove it (the fake data).

```
test('Delete categories_income Bykey', () => {
const ref = db.collection('categories_income').doc('key1');
return ref.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        ref.delete().then(() => {
            expect(mockCollection).toHaveBeenCalledWith('categories_income');
        }).catch((error) => {
            expect(error).toEqual('error')
        });
    }else{
        throw new Error("Document Does Not Exist")
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Surely that still never enters the catch? Also you don't return the inner promise chain so it's not synchronised. And you shouldn't have to change the code you're testing because of the library you're using - what happens in real life? It's unclear what's test setup and what's code you're testing - I don't think ref.delete will be reached *at all*.

Comment: But I just tested inside the promise, and it gets into int fine !! So ref-delete is reached !

Comment: I suspect if you use [`expect.assertions`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectassertionsnumber) you'll find none are reached, and the test is passing because nothing is expected rather than because the expectations are met, or failing due to an error you explicitly threw. By having assertions in both branches, it's unclear what your test is actually expecting; it can't be both.

Comment: But i am throwing error so if I change that **key1** to anything wrong the test will fail ? Should the test fail like that ?

Comment: Can I just know what I just get -1 on my solution although it works, and I test it 50 times ! You can't just put -1 when you only suspect !!! Maybe it's not the best practice ! But I believe that when something works then let it be !

Comment: With all my respect of course of your Help! But shouldn’t only be because a suspect!